# Mod_rewrite : Strange behavior with two rewrite rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have the following rules configured :

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                Options -MultiViews
                RewriteEngine On

                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/bar.php
                RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
                RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

                RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain.com|www.domain.com)
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app.php [QSA,L]
            </IfModule>
```

I want all request using HTTP to be redirected to HTTPS, except for a specific path : /foo/bar.php.

The second rule redirect everything to a web/app.php script (Symfony2).

Now everything's working, except that when I query http://domain.com/foo/bar.php, I'm getting redirected to https://domain/com/web/app.php.

If I query https://domain/com/foo/bar.php, it's working fine.

This doesn't make any sense to me, why would I be redirected to "https://domain/com/web/app.php" ? Am I missing something ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` in your first rule. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ web/app.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Damn, it's working great, thanks a lot ! (And thanks for cleaning the second rule as well ! :D)